# Graph Theory - Prove that Gn is connected if and only if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $n ≥ 3$. Define $G_n$ to be the graph where $V (G) = \{0, 1, . . . , n − 1\}$, and two vertices $a, b$ are adjacent if and only if
$a ± 3 ≡ b (\mod n)$.

Comment: just go from a = 1 by the law a->(a+3) mod n.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove by induction that $a$ and $b$ are connected if and only if $a+3x\equiv b\pmod n$ for some integer $x$, that is, if and only if the congruence
$$3x\equiv b-a\pmod n$$
has a solution.  This congruence has a solution for all $a,b$ if and only if $\gcd(3,n)=1$, that is, $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Try to create an explicit cycle that walks through all vertices for $n$ not a multiple of $3$.

If the graph is not connected, then at least two vertices are not connected. Show you can't go from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you meant by "Show you can't go from 1 to 2."

Comment: @Frank show there is no path from the vertex labeled $1$ to the vertex labeled $2$